# Insert PHP Code In PHP Variable

Tags: php

I have an simple question,

How to insert PHP code in PHP variable?

Example :

```
echo $value = "
bla
bla
<?php $q = "SELECT * FROM BLA BLA"; ?>
";
```

Comment: There is a 100% chance of a solution for your application which does not require putting PHP code into a variable the way you demonstrated.

Comment: echo $value = '
bla
bla
<?php $q = "SELECT * FROM BLA BLA"; ?>
'; like @AwladLiton mentions

Comment: It's unclear what you expect that code to do... and it smells like an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - my advice: anyone who posts an answer without figuring out what the OP really wants should be downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `eval()`

```
$test = <<<END
<p> <?php 
echo time(); 
?> </p>
END;
    
   
ob_start();
eval("?>$test");
$result = ob_get_clean();
```

Or an other example from w3s:

```
<?php
$string = "beautiful";
$time = "winter";

$str = 'This is a $string $time morning!';
echo $str. "<br>";

eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str;
?>
```

will print

> This is a $string $time morning!
>
> This is a beautiful winter morning!

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

But be very carefull when you use it, from the php page:

> Caution The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it
> allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
> If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
> use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
> provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: Please... just DON'T.

Comment: What do you mean? Don't use it?

Comment: The link to the manual could give you an idea about eval(). [Manual on eval()](http://in3.php.net/eval)